# Throwing Exception(C#) over Returning Error Number

Tags: c#, .net, exception

What are the Cons and Pros of NEW WAY(exception throwing) v.s OLD WAY(error number).

I always heard from the older generation of programmers saying the error number returning is much more robust and controllable, whereas exception throwing is good during debug time.

Which of it is a better practice of programming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exceptions give you far more contextual information such as the stack trace which is useful for diagnosing problems both during development and if you log the exception details in a production system.

There's no reason not to use both approaches. You can define your own exception type with an error code property or you can write a wrapper to extract an error number from the [data collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.data.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

when you use exception, you can trace the path o  execution that generate exception, thus this is very suitable for debugging and also the modern programming languages have some feature (like try/catch blocks) 
to manipulate exception, all of this is suitable for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Using error return codes in java or c#, where using exceptions is an option, would be to create bad code.

This would be mixing two different things, error handling and normal flow.

Don't use return values to signal error states, its bad practice, bad style and just plain silly in a modern programming language.

If someone feels the need to argue this, please do so via examples or references to literature, not just asserting.

Comment: I've never heard of a rule which states "don't use return codes to signify error codes in a modern language", so saying it always creates bad code is false. Sure exceptions give you more detail, but there's a time and place for every feature. And you don't have any examples/quotes so I don't see a need to counter with them :)

Comment: Maybe that is an indication that you need to read more.
Rule 20 in IDesigns C# coding standard states:
"Avoid error codes as method return values".
Now please do show any kind of literary reference or example that uses error codes as return values and is not poorly designed code.
Remember that OP asked the question as an either/or proposition. Often it is good design to have "something" representing error codes, but that is not what the question is about: Its about whether to use exceptions OR error return codes. The latter being the obvious wrong choice in modern languages.